# How to display image captured using Camera in Android

Tags: android

HI, 
I am writing an Android application where I need to display Image Captured through Camera.
I am using Android 2.1 I tested in emulator. I am trying to capture the image  , but how to display the captured Image on Screen.

Can anyone help me in sorting out this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `ImageView`. Or, start an `ACTION_VIEW` activity on the downloaded image file.